# How to manage file in Jedox with groovy/java(or natively) without java.nio or java.io librairies?

Tags: java, groovy, jedox

I have to manipulate file in Jedox on cloud instance and they brutaly blocked java.io and java.nio libraries.

I want to create a simple directory/create file/move file and I can't.

Is there any other library or just native function that handle this type of task in java/groovy ?
Is it possible to do it natively in jedox if you can't do it by coding anymore ?

Comment: java.io and java.nio is a built-in package to work with files/folders. What is the error when using it?

Comment: I think jedox just BLOCKED those libraries because the error message send this : "Unable to execute groovy job: Security error, 'java.io.File' not allowed" same for java.nio

Comment: i see that jedox has own file apis FileAPI and FileInfo https://software.jedox.com/doc/2022_2/jedox_integrator_scripting_api_doc_2022_2/com/jedox/etl/components/scriptapi/package-summary.html

Comment: mentioned here: https://knowledgebase.jedox.com/integration/integrator-scripting-api.htm

Comment: @daggett Yes, I know about their new FileAPI library but this library doesn't work. I tested it multiple time, and it throw the same error over and over. Plus they didn't provide any example of usage of this library and the documentation doesn't help at all.

Comment: you need admin then https://knowledgebase-onprem.jedox.com/on-prem/security/script-jobs-functions-security.htm

Comment: Okay, but this article is for on-premise version of jedox. I've got a cloud instance of jedox. I think I will try to contact the support to realize what's on this page. Thanks